# How can I check open ports on android?

Tags: android, ports

I know that every `ISO` based network system uses `TCP` port, and Android is of course not an exception.
My question is, can I check the open ports in my device? Can I close them? Is there an app to handle this issue?

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not match. Title asks if the concepts exists (of course as you realize yourself in the body) and body asks if it is possible to check what is open and close open ports. Also, the intention to close ports is not clear: ports are open if there is some service or app listening for data which means you should close the service/app.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich correct, changed it.

Comment: How do you check open ports on other systems? You can also use nmap against Android or you can use netstat if you've got a shell on the Android system (for example with adb). There is nothing special. And, if you are root you can also install your own firewall rules.

Comment: I thought a more friendly app could exist for average smartphone users. Should I delete the question?

Comment: The _average_ smartphone use does not understand the concept of TCP and ports :) And, product recommendations are off-topic here anyway. But, did you even try to search for nmap on android or similar? Because you'll actually find apps that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a terminal emulator and execute the following:

```
shell@android:/ $ cat /proc/net/tcp
```

That will list open ports.

Alternately, install an app like [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor).

If you want to close any, use a [Firewall app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall&hl=en).